# How to get a framed box with section number using memoir class?

Tags: memoir

I try to styling the section to get:

- a framed box section number
- a rule before and after section title
- box should be at middle position between rules

Currently I have this code which do not apply my section style . But even if style is successful applied, I think that a rule could appear on separate page with some bad luck. How to protect the block to be in same page ?

Thanks

MWE:

```
%!TeX encoding = utf8
%!TeX spellcheck = fr_FR
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright,openbib,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,most,listings,skins]{tcolorbox}
\checkandfixthelayout
\definecolor{bluegray}{HTML}{90C3D4}
\newcommand{\ruledsec}[1]{%
    \vskip 1em
    {\color{MidnightBlue}\hrule}
    \vskip 1em
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries#1}
    \vskip 1em
    {\color{MidnightBlue}\hrule}
}

\newtcbox{\mybox}{
    nobeforeafter,
    colframe=bluegray!40,
    colback=bluegray!40,
    colupper=white,
    boxrule=0.5pt,
    arc=4pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    right=6pt,
    top=6pt,
    bottom=6pt,
    box align=center
}
\makepagestyle{BlueBox}
\makeheadstyles{BlueBox}{
    \setsecheadstyle{\ruledsec}
}
\setsecnumformat{\csname #1secnumformat\endcsname} % numbering format
\newcommand\sectionsecnumformat{
    \hspace{-5mm}
    \mybox{\fontsize{2cm}{3.5cm}\selectfont\thesection}
    \hspace{-2mm}
}
\headstyles{BlueBox}

\begin{document}
 \chapter{chapter}
 \section{section}
 \subsection{subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is `\sectionsecnumformat` to be used? It is not something `memoir` supports and where is `\secNumFont` defined? If I feed the code from `\sectionsecnumformat` to `\setsecnumformat{}` then I do get a box

Comment: thanks @daleif , I updated the mwe  secNumFont is removed and uncomment the line setsecnumformat. The section rendering is ok but how to grant that rules an title will not be splitted in two pages.

Comment: The `lua` stuff isn't necessary here for a MWE in my point of view